# Split a long string into substrings till it is empty

Tags: apex, date, string

I tried this code to convert a string into sub-strings until the original string do not empty. Please guide where I'm wrong in it? Thanks.

```
    String dates = '01/13/2015,01/20/2015,01/27/2015,02/03/2015,02/10/2015,02/17/2015,
02/24/2015,03/03/2015,03/10/2015,03/17/2015,03/24/2015,03/31/2015,04/07/2015,
04/14/2015,04/21/2015,06/10/2015';

    Integer index=0;
    while(dates !== ""){

        //Or if possible to create an array of Date object.
        String[] eachDt = new String[]{}; 
        eachDt[index] = dates.substringBefore(",");
        index++;
    }

    System.debug(eachDt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find the substringBefore method in String methods. Please correct me if I am wrong.

In my opinion, you are simply doing:

```
List<String> eachDt = dates.split(',');
```

Just use that.

Comment: Here it is http://goo.gl/qgLs0T

And this line of code will separate each date from date string?

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid loop .. just do this :

String[] eachDt = new String[]{}; 
eachDt = dates.substringBefore(",");

and then use loop if you want to iterate the list. You  don't need index variable just to populate the list/array. substring() method returns list anyways.

Comment: My bad .. i was talking about split too.. it should be dates.split(","); instead of substring